# Why I can't get the Signed Url from amazon s3?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to get Signed Url from **Amazon s3** using **Nodejs**, I build my bucket and IAM, but after I send request from my computer using postman I always get a response said:

```
"e": {
        "message": "Missing credentials in config",
        "errno": "ETIMEDOUT",
        "code": "CredentialsError",
        "syscall": "connect",
        "address": "169.251.165.251",
        "port": 80,
        "time": "2018-08-04T17:20:32.554Z",
        "originalError": {
            "message": "Could not load credentials from any providers",
            "errno": "ETIMEDOUT",
            "code": "CredentialsError",
            "syscall": "connect",
            "address": "169.251.165.251",
            "port": 80,
            "time": "2018-08-04T17:20:32.554Z",
            "originalError": {
                "errno": "ETIMEDOUT",
                "code": "ETIMEDOUT",
                "syscall": "connect",
                "address": "169.251.165.251",
                "port": 80,
                "message": "connect ETIMEDOUT 169.251.165.251:80"
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my nodejs code:

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3()
s3.config.update({
  accessKeyId:keys.accessKeyId,
  secretAcccessKey:keys.secretAcccessKey,
  region: 'us-west-2'
});
router.get('/',
passport.authenticate('jwt',{session:false}),
(req,res)=>{
  const key =`${req.user.id}/${uuid()}.jpeg`;
  s3.getSignedUrl(
    'putObject',{
       Bucket:'NameOfBucket',
       ContentType:'jpeg',
       Key:key,
       Expires:1000
    },
   (e,url)=>res.json({e}));
});
```

Comment: check if the user with accessKeyId and secretAccesKey really has access to s3

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I check the user it has access to that bucket.

Comment: This error is **not** a permissions problem.  It suggests that there's something wrong with the values you're using for configuration... like, perhaps, they are actually empty.  Always `'use strict';`.